In my template i'm trying to hide alert massage div if the notification item is None
         {% if not notfication in alert %}
            <div style=" background: no-repeat; ">
                <div class="">
                    <span>None</span>
                
                </div>
            </div>
        {% else %}
            <div class="marquee-area">
                <div class="marquee-wrap">
                    {% for notfication in alert %}
                    <span>{{ notfication.title }}</span>
                    {% endfor %}
                </div>
            </div>
        {% endif %}

When I try to test it, regardless of whether there is data or not, I get Nothing her text

{% if not notfication in alert %} what is alert?

Check the truthiness of alert:
{% if not alert %}
    <div style=" background: no-repeat; ">
        <div class="">
            <span>None</span>
        
        </div>
    </div>
{% else %}
    <div class="marquee-area">
        <div class="marquee-wrap">
            {% for notification in alert %}
            <span>{{ notification.title }}</span>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
    </div>
{% endif %}
Usually one uses positive logic however:
{% if alert %}
    <div class="marquee-area">
        <div class="marquee-wrap">
            {% for notification in alert %}
            <span>{{ notification.title }}</span>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
    </div>
{% else %}
    <div style=" background: no-repeat; ">
        <div class="">
            <span>None</span>
        
        </div>
    </div>
{% endif %}
